# Word Choice: feat/exploit

Tags: word-choice

When I was a senior in high school, there was a contest to memorize the value of pi. I started to memorize the number the night before, and I wrote down over two hundred digits after the decimal point during the contest. This earned me first prize (a pie) and an illustrated article about my **exploits/feats** in the 2016 yearbook.

Which is a better fit here? Why?

> Choose the Right Synonym for feat (Merriam Webster)
>
> FEAT, EXPLOIT, ACHIEVEMENT mean a remarkable deed. FEAT implies
>   strength or dexterity or daring.  an acrobatic feat  EXPLOIT suggests
>   an adventurous or heroic act.  his exploits as a spy  ACHIEVEMENT
>   implies hard-won success in the face of difficulty or opposition.  her
>   achievements as a chemist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your own description from Merriam Webster, FEAT seems to be the best fit. Because in this case, it implies good memory (or good memorization skills).

It's not really something heroic or adventurous so that'd rule out EXPLOT in my opinion.

Alternatively, I also think that "Achievement" is a good fit here. But if you're doubting between feat/exploit I'd go for feat. ;-)